# How to Merge 1000 pdf's from s3 using pdfbox efficiently

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, file-io, pdfbox

I have a use case where a thousand files(pdf's) have to be downloaded from s3 bucket and merged into a single pdf. I am using java and pdfbox utility to do this.

Here is the flow:
a) Create a list of input streams.
b) Read each file from s3 using aws sdk into an input stream and add it to the list.
c) After all 1000 input streams are added to the list, use pdfbox utility and merge them into a single file.
d) Close all input streams in the list.

This seems to be working for a few pdf's(tested for 10 so far). Have to test it for more files. Here are my concerns though.

1. I am keeping all the input streams open as i need them for the merge. Even though they are closed after all the files are read, about 1000 input streams are open until all files are read. Will this cause any memory issues or any other issues ?
2. Is there any other better way to do this ?

Comment: I definitively expect memory issues unless you have a lot of memory.

Comment: How are the 1000 PDF files added to the one output PDF file?  Can you read one PDF file, write it to the output, read the next PDF file, write it to the output, and so on until all 1000 files have been processed?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr AWS does have a lot of memory but the question is whether the OP wants to pay for it ;-)